# Weird looping behavior Python when sorting files into new folders

Tags: python, loops

I've a folder with many files which I'd like to move into (to be created) subfolders (dump_1, dump_2, ...) such that each subfolder contains 100 files (or the remaining files for the last folder). For testing, I created tiny text files like so:

```
rootdir='d:/t2/'
for i in range(1000):
    f=open(rootdir+"file_"+str(i)+".txt","w")
    f.write("This is file "+str(i))
    f.close()
```

Now the code for creating subfolders and moving the files is

```
import random
files=os.listdir(rootdir)
random.shuffle(files)
count=1
while files:
    newdir=(rootdir+"dump_"+str(count).zfill(2)+"/")
    os.mkdir(newdir)
    for a,b in enumerate(files):
            os.rename(rootdir+b,newdir+b)
            files.remove(b)
            if a==99:
                break
    count+=1
```

The result is really weird: the first 9 folders contain 100 files as desired. But the next subfolders contain 50, 25, 13, 6, 3, 2 and 1 files. Does anyone have a clue why that is and how I can fix it? Thank you!

Comment: As a point of style, using both `count` and the `enumerate` loop is redundant.  You could simplify the code by removing the inner loop and just putting the code to update `newdir` inside an `if not count % 100:` block.

Comment: @sr2222 `count` is not counting the files as `a` in `enumerate` does.

Comment: @poke, without the `for` loop it would.  And you could achieve the same thing `count` is doing in the file name with `count / 100` in that case.  The code is actually less intuitive, at least imo, as currently written.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it relates with changing variable "files" in loop that enumeration above it. For example:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> for a, b in enumerate(l):
...     l.remove(b)    
...     print a
... 
0
1
2
3
4
```

Your can create a copy(or a splice) of files list in enumerate, like

```
for a, b in enumerate(files[:100]):
```

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it better to just iterate through the files and create new directory when necessary:

```
import random
files = os.listdir(rootdir)
random.shuffle(files)
count = 1
newdir = None
for filename in files:
    if count % 100 == 1 or newdir is None:
        newdir = rootdir + "dump_" + str(count).zfill(2) + "/"
        os.mkdir(newdir)
    os.rename(rootdir + filename, newdir + filename)
    count += 1
```

It saves cycles and makes the logic clear. Also, from the original I have not understood if batches should be 99 or 100 files. But it's easy to change 100 to 99. Also, there is no need to remove files from the list.

Comment: ... Except you should still use the `enumerate` trick from the original code to avoid having to update `count` manually.

Answer (score 0):

`enumerate` iterates over the elements of the list. As a generator it does each iteration when it’s requested. Now in your loop you are removing items from the list as you are still iterating over it.

That way when you remove the *current* element, the generator is already pointing at the next element before it generates the next iteration. So in result it skips over every second entry:

```
>>> myList = [i for i in range(10)]
>>> for i, j in enumerate(myList):
        print(i, j)
        myList.remove(j)

0 0
1 2
2 4
3 6
4 8
```

Now what you can do is to either create a copy for your iteration so that the enumeration itself isn’t affected by the removals. The other way would be to improve your whole loop so you do not actually need to remove elements from the list.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for all the help! I tried to combine all of it in the code below and it runs like a charm!

```
rootdir='d:/t2/'
import random
files = os.listdir(rootdir)
random.shuffle(files)
newdir = None
for n,filename in enumerate(files):
    if n%100 == 0 or newdir is None:
        newdir = rootdir + "dump_" + str(divmod(n,100)[0]).zfill(2) +"/"
        os.mkdir(newdir)
    os.rename(rootdir + filename, newdir + filename)
```